# Pros and cons of using charcoal on a canvas

Tags: material-selection, charcoal, canvas

I have a commission due this Christmas, it has to be on a 40 x 30 canvas, and the whole drawing has to be in charcoal, so I want to know if it'd be the same thing as if I was drawing on paper. Or should I change to paper instead of a canvas? What would work best?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It depends on what you want to draw, and in what style.**

Working with charcoal on canvas will really emphasize the texture of the canvas, creating a rough impression. It will be hard to draw details - in relation to the size, that is: you can still draw details but they'll have to be larger or implied rather than drawn carefully.

Coincidentally I've recently visited an Ilya Repin exhibition, and he made a few charcoal drawings on canvas as well (I'm not sure if they were preparatory sketches).
Below is a detail of approximately 40 x 71 cm (more than twice the size of your canvas) from one of those works:

[image: Detail of Ilya Repin's Portrait of Vera Pushkareva, made with charcoal on canvas in 1899]
<sup>Ilya Repin | Portrait of Vera Pushkareva (detail) | charcoal on canvas | 1899.

The complete work can be seen [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/183298784@N08/51680373948/). Mind that facial features and other details are drawn with pencil.</sup>

As you can see, a lot of the texture pushes through, and creates a noise, bringing to mind high ISO photography, or old television imagery, at times even glitches (where the canvas has a repeating pattern, which will be more obvious on linen).
For sketches it works quite well since it's easier to create an impression, as a higher amount of noise tends to be easier to be interpreted visually.

All this is naturally dependent on the roughness of the canvas, as you will be able to find canvases with a very fine weave, but never without texture (and will likely cost you more).

Another option, if you've set your mind to working on canvas but don't want to sacrifice detail, is to ground the canvas with an acrylic base and wipe it level with the bumps in the texture. It's not easy to get it perfectly smooth, though.

Other considerations:
I assume a drawing on paper would be framed, so both objects would be around the same size, with fixed dimensions. Unless you're framing a drawing on canvas, it would be more receptive to dirt and damage. But it would also be more of a statement.

Comment: Thanks joachim! 
So to not sacrifice detail, no canvas...
Is there a way i can use a big paper and put it in like a piece of wood without not making any damage to the paper? like, the drawing is ment to last yearssss, and i dont want anything to happen to it, would this option do anything to the paper in the long term??

(thx for your time)

Comment: You mean like a wooden cylindrical casing?

Comment: uhmm, i think thats too much for a paper, i want it to be just as if it was a canvas, but with a paper (for the sake of details)

Comment: @Isaac750 You mean you want to stretch paper on a frame?

Comment: no, that would break the paper whenever i lay the pencil down on it

Comment: @Isaac750, a possibility to explore: bond appropriate paper to the stretched canvas using something like a spray adhesive.  The canvas would provide strength, and the canvas plus a bonded heavyweight paper might be stiff enough to draw on with minimal embossing.  Alternative: create the drawing on paper and apply fixative.  Then bond it to the stretched canvas, being careful with the drawing surface.

Comment: I have made many paintings on paper stretched on a frame. It's not hard to do, and the surface is wonderful to work on.

Comment: alr, thanks joachim, ill do that, ill have to fine a 30x40 paper! ouch, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've created numerous paintings with rough sketch on the first layer of canvas. I would imagine it would depend on the roughness of the canvas. I have not personally tried to do a final piece on a piece of canvas with just pencil or charcoal. Only light outlines. Prime canvas would be even more difficult to achieve because it gives a waxy layer on top of the canvas. The pencil would have a hard time sticking to the canvas without wiping it away. I don't think it is impossible. Like Joachim mentioned, it would be have grain and noise element to it as well, which would be a learning curve.

Pros: different, broad strokes not as much detail
Cons: Not for beginners, canvas texture learning curve